# Anchor tag link to ID on different page with animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have 2 page website, im trying to link second page back to first page where the div is present im trying with.

```
<li class="menuitem">
    <a href="index.html#services">Go Back</a>
</li>
```

It goes to the div with id tag services and leaves the id tag on address bar.

Im trying to animate it to the place and remove id tag from the address bar.

this is how page 1 looks like -

```
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="gallery"></div>
<div id="services"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

jquery used for linking div in same page -

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. you need javascript or jquery and plugins
2. you could combine your content into 1 page considering you only have 2, much easier to navigate and animate etc.

Answer (score 1):

with `window.location.hash` you can read and write the hash-value. So on pageload you do basically the following:

```
$("html, body").animate({ 
   scrollTop: $('#'+window.location.hash).offset().top 
}, 1000);
window.location.hash='';
```

Comment: nice idea i did not think this one

Comment: dont have much experience in jquery, i have added jquery im using to animate to div in the page can i pass this in that to animate back to services from the other page?

Comment: If you add the code above on the document-load the DOM-Element were the id is the same as the hash will be scroll in view. Do you change content by HTTP-Request (e.g. a link) or by DOM-manipulation (e.g. by jQuery)?

Comment: its a static website, it is still doing samething as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify URL after it loaded you have to play with your request

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Try using cookie storing and then using jquery you can focus on that one

Or using javscript

```
window.onload=getloaded();
function getloaded() {    
      var g=document.URL ;
      if(g.indexOf('services')!=-1) {
          // focus on services
      }
}
```

or like this

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#your element").offset().top},'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use anchor tag with

```
href="my_page.html#my_anchor_name"
```

which will scroll to any html element with id equal to `my_anchor_name` in the page `my_page.html` provided the page belongs to the same domain.
If you want to link within the same page, simply omit the page name `my_page.html`.